# How to pass runtime variable (datetime) in scala

Tags: scala, gatling

Consider the following scenario...

```
import java.util.Calendar

val timestamp = Calendar.getInstance.getTime   \\ I have defined the timestamp variable
```

Following my request which i wanted to pass the runtime datetime value.

```
.exec(http("request_6")
.post("/abcd/projects")
.headers(headers_29)
.formParam("Id", "5")
.formParam("extra", """{"inputproname":"+timestamp+","textareadesc":""")) \\ passing the same timestamp here
```

Scala script has been successfully executed but it created as name with << +timestamp+ >> instead of actual timestamp value

So can anyone tell me what am i doing wrong here? how to pass the time timestamp variable ???

Your help would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Praveen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first option reads better...

```
s"""{"inputproname":"$timestamp","textareadesc":"""

"""{"inputproname":""""+timestamp+"""","textareadesc":"""

"{\"inputproname\":\""+timestamp+"\",\"textareadesc\":"
```

Comment: thanks Mr Pinson, It is working for me.........:)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        "{\"inputproname\":\""+timestamp+"\",\"textareadesc\":"

Comment: Just being curios, I just want to know, why we need escaping for all the fields in formParam(.\.\.\). Can't I do escaping only for 'timestamp' field??? thanks! Praveen

Comment: With all the quote marks it can be confusing. There are really three strings here being concatenated together. So on the last option, "{\"inputproname\":\"", is a string literal, meaning everything between the first and last double-quote is a Char. And, as I am sure you know, to avoid confusing the compiler, all double-quote chars need to be escaped with the backslash character.